# get detail json in react

Tags: json, reactjs

```js
datajs = fetch(Constants.SPS_S_INVESTIGATOR_QB).then(async (response) => {
  const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
  if (contentType && contentType.indexOf('application/json') !== -1) {
    const jsn = await response.json();
    return jsn['DBInfoScript'].replace('var ourDB=', '');
  } else {
    const text = await response.text();
  }
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (dataItem.length == 0) {
    setdataItem(datajs);
  }
}, [datajs]);
console.log(dataItem);

console.log(dataItem.airtravel);
```

I want get detail json but Output is undefined
output console.log(dataItem.airtravel) output = undefind
but console.log(dataItem) out put is full
Photo below the console output from console.log(dataItem)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the "dataItem" object. can you comment JSON output of "dataItem"?

Comment: Hi Afzal I putting up output of "dataItem"